# How does a JavaScript developer find implementing classes of an interface?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, iterable, ecmascript-2016

I am learning JavaScript, and I am coming from Java.

A Java developer can easily evaluate the usefulness of an interface, because all known implementing classes are documented. Please click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) to see an example.

The same is not true in JavaScript. For example, for iterables, the links below show only a few examples of iterables.  They don't show all implementing built-in and DOM classes.  (For example, they mentioned "collection types such as NodeList are also iterables". So, other than NodeList, how can I find the other DOM classes that are iterables? Are there some JS codes I can run to achieve this? Thanks!)

How does a JavaScript developer find implementing classes of an interface?

Thanks!

#### MDN Documentation on iterables:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#built-in_iterables
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator#description

#### Update 1:

What I am looking for are iterables that can go into the first argument of [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to find all the implementing classes? As long as it implements the interface, you don't need to know anything else.

Comment: New classes that implement the interface can be added all the time, as well as being added by user code. So any list will necessarily be incomplete.

Comment: Even the list you linked to is only implementations in the standard Java classes, it doesn't include implementations added by third party libraries or user-written code.

Comment: `New classes that implement the interface can be added all the time, as well as being added by user code. So any list will necessarily be incomplete. `
Hi @Barmar, I don't need a complete list of all the 3rd party or external or user libraries.  I am hoping to at least know what kind of standard built-in and DOM interfaces (in es6 and es7) support iterables.  I assume es6 and es7 don't change that often (they tend to have a new version only once every 10 years)

Comment: `Even the list you linked to is only implementations in the standard Java classes, it doesn't include implementations added by third party libraries or user-written code. `
Hi @Barmar, for my college, they only expect the instructors to know about the standard classes.  They don't expect the instructors to know about 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for all the feedbacks. I am teaching a course in JavaScript. One of the lectures is about the Array.from() method. Without knowing what goes into the first argument of Array.from(), I can't claim that I am qualified to teach this topic.

Comment: You don't need an exhaustive list for that. Examples of the kinds of things is enough.

Comment: JavaScript and DOM are evolving standards. Even the built-in types will keep changing.

Comment: The title of your question asks "how", but the body is again asking "*what other DOM classes are iterables?*" which duplicates [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185613/in-javascript-where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-built-in-iterables-and-dom-it).

Comment: Hi @Bergi , `The title of your question asks "how", but the body is again asking "what other DOM classes are iterables? which duplicates your previous question`  , I have changed the question from "what" to "how".  Please kindly review.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `Array.from()` is a static method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the closest we get to "interface" when it comes to built in classes might be well-known symbols that tells us whether a class implements something:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#well-known_symbols

We can get all properties of the globalThis (same as the Window object in browsers, different in Node.js) object, most that are classes are not enumerable, so we have to use **Object.getOwnPropertyNames**.

We can then loop through them and see if their prototypes are **iterable** - have the well-known symbol **Symbol.iterator.**

We will now get an extensive list of classes that create iterable instances.

```js
function getIterableClasses() {
  let classNames = [];
  let builtIn = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globalThis);
  for (let x of builtIn) { 
    try {
      let object = globalThis[x].prototype;
      object[Symbol.iterator] && classNames.push(x);
    }
    catch (e) { }
  }
  return classNames.sort();
}

let c = getIterableClasses();
console.log('Found ' + c.length + ' iterable classes');
console.log(c.join('\n'));
```

This code reports 68 built-in classes that create iterables in Chrome, 58 in Firefox and 57 in Safari (latest versions of the browsers on a Mac, 6th of May 2023). So there are quite a few of these classes.

*Note:* In **Node.js** the list is much smaller, since it has a more modular structure (modules are required/imported when needed) and don't have any DOM-related classes, but you still get 19 different classes with iterable instances in Node.js: *Array, BigInt64Array, BigUint64Array, Buffer, Float32Array, Float64Array, FormData, Headers, Int16Array, Int32Array, Int8Array, Map, Set, String, URLSearchParams, Uint16Array, Uint32Array, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray*.

*A personal thought from one teacher to another:* If your purpose is to teach basic JavaScript I think you will do both yourself and your students a disfavor in going through all these classes. Rather focus on some basics: arrays are iterable, strings are iterable, NodeLists are (and how to use *querySelectorAll* to get NodeLists). And the fact that you can turn any iterable into an array by spreading it into an array *[...iterable]* is often useful since you can then use standard array methods (like *map, filter, reduce*) on it.

Also: Spreading an iterable into an array *[...iterable]* does about the same thing as *Array.prototype.from* but in a shorter more 'JS-nesque' way.

Comment: Updated the answer - found a much better angle - now I find 68 built in classes that creates iterables - when running this code in Chrome, try it yourself by clicking "Run code snippet".

Comment: Why use `Object.create` instead of using `.prototype` directly?

Comment: What is the point of `if (x === 'getIterableClasses'){continue;}`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko: Good catch. Will change my code!

Comment: @Bergi: To avoid an endless loop since the function itself becomes part of window if run in a  console/global scope (which is a natural place to run it)- but that was before when i used new I think so it is unnecessary now. Good catch! Will remove!

Comment: Fixed and upvoted your comments @SolomonUcko and Bergi